# Starting selenium standalone from Jenkins in Unix server

Tags: windows, batch-file, selenium, jenkins, ssh

I am trying to start a selenium standalone server as part of a pre build step to ensure the remote machine (Windows) has a selenium standalone server up and running before the automation code starts execution, I have written a batch file in the windows server which i am able to access from the Jenkins using ssh command, but the server starts and stops even before the tests run.

```
Batch commands    
start Java -jar selenium-standalone-server-2.47.1.jar

Jenkins Commands
ssh username@host "batchFile.bat"
```

> [SELENIUM] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/hudson6388101916998949633.sh
>   + ssh {username}@{host} '{folder_path}\batchFile.bat'
>
> C:\Users\{username}>start java -jar C:\Users\
>   {username}\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-server-
>   standalone\2.47.1\selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar

The server starts and ends before the next steps in the Jenkins job are able to execute.

Comment: hey Nikhil, did you get a solution for this? I am in same situation.

Comment: No we could not automate this, so we configured the selenium server to run at start up of the windows machine. The downside is if the automation scripts are running and for any reason the standalone server is not running then all the scripts fail. There is a manual intervention required if the server stops in the windows machine.